# Network share not accessible by IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

Overnight one of our servers (Win 2K8 R2) began having problems connecting to a network share (Win 2K3 R2 x64) by IP.

The server has for months accessed the network share by IP for certain purposes, and the previous server it replaced did so as well.

The server can access the network share by name.

The server can ping the network share server by both name and IP.

Every other computer on the network can access the network share by name and IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying you can ping the IP from the server and clients, and you can connect to the server's share by name (\servername\share) but not IP (\192.x.x.x\share)...

This implies something has the IP, but it isn't the server. And since you can connect by name, DNS is resolving to whatever the server currently has.

When you ping the server with that share from a client, is the correct IP coming up? What does the server say the IP is?

Are there entries in the log indicating that another server or device is using that IP and there's a "fight" for the IP on the network?

Comment: When I ping the share server name the correct IP comes up. Which log would hold the error/fight info?

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Not seeing anything obvious in event viewer.